# How can I enable setting breakpoints in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I've been working with Visual Studio for some time now but somehow the option to put breakpoints near the line numbers has disappeared. How do I re-enable it? Here's a little screenshot:

http://gyazo.com/284a97eaf078bc103c113d7c56b18fd4

I want to be able to put breakpoints on the left side. I can put breakpoints at methods but that's not what I'm searching for right now.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear. From what I understood though, you could try fixing the issue this way:

Go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > General`

Ensure that option `Indicator margin` is checked.

The left-side gray strip should now appear and you should be able to put breakpoints in it.